# R: show matched special character in a string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

How can I show which special character was a match in each row of the single column dataframe?

Sample dataframe:

```
a <- data.frame(name=c("foo","bar'","ip_sum","four","%23","2_planet!","@abc!!"))
```

determining if the string has a special character:

```
a$name_cleansed <- gsub("([-./&,])|[[:punct:]]","\\1",a$name) #\\1 puts back the exception we define (dash and slash)

a <- a %>% mutate(has_special_char=if_else(name==name_cleansed,FALSE,TRUE))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str_extract` if we want only first special character.

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(a$name,'[[:punct:]]')
#[1] NA  "'" "_" NA  "%" "_" "@"
```

If we need all of the special characters we can use `str_extract_all`.

```
sapply(str_extract_all(a$name,'[[:punct:]]'), function(x) toString(unique(x)))
#[1] ""     "'"    "_"    ""     "%"    "_, !" "@, !"
```

To exclude certain symbols, we can use

```
exclude_symbol <- c('-', '.', '/', '&', ',')

sapply(str_extract_all(a$name,'[[:punct:]]'), function(x) 
                       toString(setdiff(unique(x), exclude_symbol)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `grepl` here for a base R option:

```
a$has_special_char <- grepl("(?![-./&,])[[:punct:]]", a$name, perl=TRUE)
a$special_char <- ifelse(a$has_special_char, sub("^.*([[:punct:]]).*$", "\\1", a$name), NA)
a

       name has_special_char special_char
1       foo            FALSE         <NA>
2      bar'             TRUE            '
3    ip_sum             TRUE            _
4      four            FALSE         <NA>
5       %23             TRUE            %
6 2_planet!             TRUE            !
7    @abc!!             TRUE            !
```

**Data:**

```
a <- data.frame(name=c("foo","bar'","ip_sum","four","%23","2_planet!","@abc!!"))
```

The above logic returns, arbitrarily, the first symbol character, if present, in each name, otherwise returning `NA`.  It reuses the `has_special_char` column to determine if a symbol occurs in the name already.

**Edit:**

If you want a column which shows *all* special characters, then use:

```
a$all_special_char <- ifelse(a$has_special_char, gsub("[^[:punct:]]+", "", a$name), NA)
```

Comment: my original post shows there are characters excluded, can you edit your answer based on that please?

Comment: @Ibo Check the updated answer.  In the `grepl` logic now I have a negative lookahead which exclues the few symbols you want to spare.  The rest of the script and output actually remain the same from this change.

Comment: it only shows the last special character if there were multiple though

Comment: Do you want to see all characters?  I will update now.  Also, the answer you accepted does not exclude the symbols you want to preserve.

Answer (score 0):

Base R regex solution using (caret) not "^" operator:

```
gsub("(^[-./&,])|[^[:punct:]]", "", a$name)
```

Also if you want a data.frame returned:

```
within(a, {
  special_char <- gsub("(^[-./&,])|[^[:punct:]]", "", name); 
  has_special_char <- special_char != ""})
```

If you only want unique special characters per name as in @Ronak Shah's answer:

```
within(a, {
    special_char <- sapply(gsub("(^[-./&,])|[^[:punct:]]", "", a$name),
                           function(x){toString(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, ""))))});
    has_special_char <- special_char != ""
  }
```